# Convert digitalWrite() in Arduino into STM32

Tags: arduino, stm32

I am trying to translate my arduino code into stm32 code for my own learning.
I was trying to convert the following code into stm32 code

```
      digitalWrite(main2, HIGH);
      delay(main_delay);
      digitalWrite(main1, LOW);
```

by using the following but it wasnt working. It would be really appreciated if you guys can help me out.

```
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
  HAL_Delay(1000);
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
```

Comment: You might want to read the manual or examples how to set the states of GPIO pins. What you are now doing is just changing a variable in a struct, and that struct is used to configure IO pin strength, mode and direction.

Comment: Look for `HAL_GPIO_WritePin();`

Comment: Hi! Also, the design methodology of using explicit delays (for a whole Second?) is something that you won't find as often in "real-world firmwares"  (we'd use a timer for that, and if we've got nothing else to do in the meantime, go to sleep). It's kind of an "arduinoism", if you want. It might really be worth that when coming from the arduino world, going to a RTOS to work really directly on your metal, but still get facilities like multi-tasking. That's just my two cents – but I've never started out on Arduino, so maybe I'm not the perfect person to advise on that from experience.

Comment: Note also, the two Arduino calls are to two different ports while your replacement writes the same port twice.